# Lazarus: Why OnDrawTab event is not executing?

Tags: events, tabs, controls, lazarus

On a form, I have a TTabControl. Plus, I have created the OnDrawTab and OnChange event accordingly. However, only OnChange Event works but not the OnDrawTab event.

What am I doing wrong or Is there a way around it?

I placed a breakpoint within OnDrawTab event and it just won't break at that point.

I am running Lazarus 1.0.12 and fpc 2.6.2 on Linux OS.

Comment: My first guess was that you forgot to set the `OwnerDraw` property to True, but now when I'm looking at the implementation of the `TTabControl.Paint` method it seems that this control does not support owner drawing at all (Lazarus 1.0.12).

Comment: Yes, I did look and there is a property, OwneDraw. I did set it to True. Still, it made no difference.

Comment: I think it is because the native OS's tab control does not support such ability. So, you need to find some alternative solution instead using TTabControl.

Comment: Take a look at [ATTabs](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/ATTabs) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much researching, I ended up trying out ATTabs. It does need some editing to be able to run on Linux Environment. I am able to use it with Lazarus.

Thanks for the suggestion.